# how to test uploading and downloading speed in ios programmatically

Tags: ios, networking

how to calculate upload speed as well as download speed separately.

How to determine the speed on internet programmatically?
like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First capture start time of download or upload task, I mean when you start download or upload capture or store your current system time something like,

```
   NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Then you can check your `download or upload speed` like,

```
   double yourSpeed = bytesTransferred / ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime);
```

`bytesTransferred`, you can got from `delegate methods` of your `NSURlSession` or `NSUrlConnection` whatever you are using!!!

Comment: plz provide full code